# How to implement controller in order to handle the creation of one or more than one record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, save

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1. I have a "nested" model and in its controller I would like to make the RESTful `create` action to handle cases when one or more than one records are submitted. That is, my controller `create` action is:

```
def create
  @nester = Nester.find(:nester_id)
  @nesters_nested_objects = @nester.nested_objects.build(create_params)

  if @nnesters_ested_objects.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end

def create_params
  params.require(:nesters_nested_object).permit(:attr_one, :attr_two, :attr_three)
end
```

I  would like it to handle both cases when `params` contain data related to one object and when it contains data related to more than one object.

How can I make that? Should I implement a new controller action (maybe called `create_multiple`) or what? There is a common practice in order to handling these cases?

Comment: I believe the common practice is to create nested records along with the parent ones with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: @Almaron - In my case the action is intended to be used for public API and I can/would not use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: well, then I suppose you could take an array from params and itterate through it.

Comment: @Almaron - Should I implement a new controller action (maybe called create_multiple) or what?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist on creating those records aside from their nest, I can propose to go with something like this (it better be a separate method really):

```
def create_multiple
  @nest = Nester.find(params[:nester])
  params[:nested_objects].each do |item|
    @nest.nested.new(item.permit(:attr_one, :attr_two, :attr_three))
  end
  if @nest.save
     ....
  else
     ....
  end
end
```